# Remove files from unix server when extend a specific limit

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have written a script to retrieve the data usage from a unix server and send an email to inform my colleagues. Now i want to insert in the if statement a block in order to delete some files that are two days old +.

I have tried the remove command but i am a bit lost with the path (btw the files are store in the unix server). Please find below my code

```
    SPACE=$(df -P /data |tail -1 |awk '{print $5}' |cut -d '%' -f1)
echo $SPACE
if [ "$SPACE" -gt 75 ]; then
    echo "Warning you run out of space,Please delete from server" | mailx -r sender@mail.com -s "server_Data_Usage" receiver@mail.com
else
    echo "Enough space " | mailx -r sender@mail.com -s "server_Data_Usage" receiver@mail.com
fi
```

Thanks in advance,
Panos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use `find` command to do that easily like below:

```
 find /data/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 | xargs rm
```

In the above command `find` will search for all the files under /data and list down files that are 2 days older and through pipe it will redirect to `rm` command which will delete the files permanently.

Now you need to modify your script like below:-

```
SPACE=$(df -P /data |tail -1 |awk '{print $5}' |cut -d '%' -f1)
echo $SPACE
if [ "$SPACE" -gt 75 ]; then
    echo "Warning you run out of space,Please delete from server" | mailx -r   sender@mail.com -s "server_Data_Usage" receiver@mail.com
    find /data/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 | xargs rm
else
    echo "Enough space " | mailx -r sender@mail.com -s "server_Data_Usage" receiver@mail.com
fi
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Many Thanks @Abhijit Pritam !! You helped me a ton! it effeminately worked.

Comment: Hey done ! May i ask you something ? the below code does my job perfectly to delete the files i want.  "find /data/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 | xargs rm" Even though i do not use the "-mindepth 1 " command. Also i searched on the internet and i cannot find what it does? Could you please explain it ? As far as i understand is to check the file size? to be more than "1"? or something like that?

Comment: That is parameter to find command to limit the search for files in file system. You can remove it if you don't have any sub directories inside /data